# Java - ServerSocket error

Tags: java, serversocket

I'm attempting to receive a message from another computer, with a simple chat client.

I'm getting this error in the Console:

```
Starting Listener.......
Could not listen on that port
error: null
```

I get this in the Console when I send text over.

Here's my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer
{
   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
      {

         System.out.println("Starting Listener.......");

         try{

             ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(5060);

             while(true)
             {

                //
                // Read a message sent by client application
                //
            Socket clientSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();   
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                String message = (String) ois.readObject();
                System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);

             }


         }
         catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("Could not listen on that port");
             System.out.println("error: "+e.getMessage());
             System.exit(-1);
         }

      }
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing that's causing that null value?  For that matter, what's causing the catch exception when I send a text string over.

Comment: In your exception handler, add e.printStackTrace(); to get a more detailed reason...

Comment: And don't guess at the cause of the error: use the actual exception and error provided. It may have nothing to do with listening at that port.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.out.println("error: "+e) to see the exception type which should provide more detail on what exactly went wrong - Java's class library exceptions are notorious for not including a message detailing the problem (and have only started getting better about this in recent releases).

Also, your catch of IOException will include any errors using the socket, including your attempt to read from a listen socket, so your error handling is misleading and insufficient.

Comment: @coffeemonitor So you probably aren't writing an object at the other end.